# Git doesn't work after a clean installation using macports due to libcurl.4.dylib version?

Tags: macos, git, curl, https, macports

I have a Mac OSX Lion 10.7.5 and the latest macports version 2.3.1. After successfully installing git I get the following error trying to clone a repository:

```
/Users/bravegag/code$ git --version
git version 2.1.2
/Users/bravegag/code$ git clone http://github.com/MTG/sms-tools.git
Cloning into 'sms-tools'...
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /opt/local/libexec/git-core/git-remote-http
  Reason: Incompatible library version: git-remote-http requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0
```

Can anyone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: What do `otool -L /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib`, `port provides /opt/local/lib/libcurl.4.dylib` and `port -v installed curl` print?

Comment: Oh, and you don't happen to have `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` set in your environment, do you? If you have, please remove it – it doesn't behave like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux and setting it on OS X is in virtually all cases wrong (and not required).

Comment: Thank you @neverpanic I will checkout these suggestions and see how they go. How about creating a proper answer instead of adding many comments?

Comment: Those aren't actually answers, just questions that help diagnose the problem further. I've been yelled at on this site before for posting steps like these (even if they are very likely the correct solution) as answer.

Comment: @neverpanic ok commenting out the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in my ~/.bashrc solves the problem. Add a proper answer and I will gladly accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you don't have DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set. It is generally not necessary on OS X and only useful for development. If you need it for a tool, you should contact the tool author to get their linking fixed, because libraries are usually referenced using absolute paths on OS X.